# How to access xml node value on the basis of sibling node value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have a xml i.e

```
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

i get the value of author using xml dom parser in javascript. now i want to get the value of price node corresponding to value of author i get. how can i acheive this. for author i'm using this

```
var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("author");
var array = [];
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
 array.push(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  alert(array.toString());
  }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is iterating on `x.nextElementSibling` until you get the correct `x.nodeName`. But I don't like this approach; it's finicky and fragile.

Rather, I'd not search by `"author"`, but by `"book"`; then iterate each book, and call `book.getElementsByTagName('author')[0]` and `book.getElementsByTagName('price')[0]`. Or if you really need to search for `"author"`, then you can go to `author.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('price')[0]`.

**EDIT:** To get a price for a specific author, I'd rather use XPath:

```
function priceForAuthor(author, xmldoc) {
  var escapedAuthor = JSON.stringify(author);
  var xpath = '//author[text()=' + escapedAuthor + ']/../price/text()';
  var price = xmldoc.evaluate(
    xpath,
    x.documentElement,
    null,
    XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE,
    null
  ).numberValue;
  return price;
}

priceForAuthor("J K. Rowling", xmldoc);
// => 29.99
```

Comment: i want to get the value of price on the basis of value of author i get... suppose  i get "J K. Rowling" value of author then i want to get the value of price on the basis of J K. Rowling.

Comment: Your code does not show "author you get", but extracting all prices (for all authors). Can you clarify your input and your output?

Comment: i am geeting the value of author by this piece of code var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("author");
var array = [];
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
 array.push(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  alert(array.toString());
  }

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, still. You copy/pasted what you have in your question. Do you want all authors and corresponding prices (as your code indicates), or do you ask for a specific author and want to find a price for that author (as your comment indicates)?

Comment: yes i have specific author and want to find a price for that author

Comment: thanks mate 1 more queston if my value is not neumeric its a string than i have to replace .numberValue with Value of no need of it ?

Comment: `NUMBER_TYPE` -> `STRING_TYPE`, and `numberValue` -> `stringValue`. And if you have the possibility of multiple results, then it is a bit different still (you will need an iterator). Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript).